# Data read from a file doesn't show up inside the JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need help in making the data read from within a file appear inside the JTable. And yes, I've already searched for answers before I asked and unfortunately, my problem still persists.
Here is a sample code for you to see what's happening:

```
      import java.awt.*;
      import java.io.*;
      import java.util.*;
      import javax.swing.*;

      public class Inventory extends JFrame {

      public JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel(); 
      public JLabel jlabel3 = new JLabel();
      public static int i = 0;

      public static void main(String[] args) {

      Inventory invent = new Inventory();

      }//main

      public Inventory() {

          //super("Inventory");
          getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
          getContentPane().setLayout(null);

          setSize(400, 350);
          setVisible(true);
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setResizable(true);
          Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
          this.setLocation(dim.width/2-this.getSize().width/2, 
          dim.height/2-this.getSize().height/2);

          jLabel2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
          jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 153));
          jLabel2.setText("Our Products:");
          getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
          jLabel2.setBounds(120, 10, 240, 20);


          String[] inventoryHeading = {"Item ID", "Item Name", 
                                       "Item Description", "Item Price", "Item Stock"};

          String inventoryArr[][] = new String[100][5];


          try {

                      File items = new File("inventory.dat");
                      Scanner itemScanner = new Scanner(items);


                      while(itemScanner.hasNext()) {

                           String line      = itemScanner.nextLine();
                           String[] inventoryFile = line.split("; "); 

                           String itemID        = inventoryFile[0]; 
                           String itemName      = inventoryFile[1];
                           String itemDescr     = inventoryFile[2];
                           String itemPrice     = inventoryFile[3];
                           String itemStock     = inventoryFile[4];

                           for(int col = 0; col > 5; col++)    {

                               inventoryArr[i][col] = itemID;
                               col = col+1;

                               inventoryArr[i][col] = itemName;
                               col = col+1;

                               inventoryArr[i][col] = itemDescr;
                               col = col+1;

                               inventoryArr[i][col] = itemPrice;
                               col = col+1;

                               inventoryArr[i][col] = itemStock;

                               i++;

                           }//for

        }//while

    }//try

        catch(FileNotFoundException e1) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error! File: inventory.dat not found!", 
                                                "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }//catch

        JTable table = new JTable(inventoryArr, inventoryHeading);   
        JScrollPane scrollTable = new JScrollPane(table); 

        scrollTable.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollTable.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollTable.setViewportView(table);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        jlabel3.add(scrollTable);
        getContentPane().add(jlabel3);
        getContentPane().add(scrollTable);
        scrollTable.setBounds(0, 40, 400, 260);
        jlabel3.setBounds(0, 40, 400, 260);

        scrollTable.setVisible(true);
        table.setVisible(true);
        }//Inventory()

        }//inventory class
```

I hope someone could help. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by manually incrementing `col` variable inside the loop?

Comment: It's for assigning the values from the file into their corresponding fields / columns in the array. Every line of the file  supposedly has records for each of the 5 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the `for` loop--it's never being executed.  Specifically:

```
for (int col = 0; col > 5; col++)
```

This is bad because you are asking for `col` to be **greater than** five, not **less than** five.  So, change that sign.

Secondly, you shouldn't increment `col` within the `for` loop -- the loop does that for you already.

Finally, don't increment `i` at every iteration of the `for` loop, do so outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

### Few things

(haven't test but seem like problems)

1. `i++;`, You have it inside the `for` loop. That means you are increasing the row for every column cell you put the value for. You probably want to move the `i++` out side of the `for` loop, so that every *line* the `i`(row) increases (But then again, your entire  for loop is disfunctional - better to get rid of it)
2. `while(itemScanner.hasNext())`. I would use `hasNextLine()`
3. Unless you are sure about exactly 100 rows, I would use something more dynamic. For that we need to deal with the `TableModel`, which you should be anyway, when working with tables. For example, using a [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

   ```
   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(inventoryHeading, 0);
   while (itemScanner.hasNextLine()) {
       String line = lineScanner.nextLine().trim();
       // split and apply varaibles and values
       Object[] row = {itemId, itemName, itemDesc, itemPrice, itemStock};
       ...
       model.addRow(row);
   }
   JTable table = new JTable(model);
   ```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. But please take note the number 3 in my answer. When working with tables, you _should_ work with `TableModel` when handing the data. See more at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and the [DefaultTableModel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)